# Relation between a column vector and coordinate system.

Tags: matrices, analytic-geometry, vector-analysis, coordinate-systems

When we write a vector as a column matrix,what coordinate system does it correspond to.If it's the Cartesian system, does it mean that when we write vectors in other coordinate systems,we use the same form of column matrix,but replace each coordinate with those of corresponding system?

Comment: Writing $v=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)^T$ as column vector does not correspond to a coordinate system. We just have $a_i\in K$ and $V=K^n$ as a vector space.

Comment: It is recommended to watch the following video to enhance the understanding of the matrix. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab&index=3

Comment: If you have in mind elements of $\mathbb K^n$ for some field $\mathbb K$, then there’s a subtle distinction between those vectors and their coordinates relative to some basis that comes into play. As @DietrichBurde commented, the vectors are just tuples of scalars with no reference to a basis. It happens that their coordinates relative to the so-called standard basis of $\mathbb K^n$ are identical to them, so they are often tacitly identified. When speaking of the _coordinates_ of a vector, if there’s no explicit basis mentioned, then some standard basis is assumed.